# Making A Quiz like program

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to create a "quiz" where the user will be asked a question and if the user can't answer it they can't move to the next question until they answer it correctly. I know this question may sound elementary but I am a novice in programming and am trying to create my first real program.

So basically I would like to know what approach I should take if I want the user to be able to return back to their quiz if they leave or can't complete it. That's why I don't think Javascript would work because it's not sever side and won't save anything. Again sorry if this is very basic.

Comment: Suggest finding a programming book and learn to program. Any elementary book should help. Come back if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with PHP. Find a good learning environment that works for you. Learn the basics of PHP. Get a local server running on your machine.

This is how I would get started...

1. Store your questions and answers in a database giving each a unique id.
2. Securely advance the user to the next question, only if they have answered the pervious one correctly.
3. Store the user's progress somewhere; either server-side, or on the user's machine (Through a session or cookie)
4. Have a page that displays the questions, using a given id.
   mysite.com/question.php?id=x
5. When the user views the page, Compare that id to whatever the COOKIE is.
   if they match, show that question.

Now we write some ...

When the quiz starts, set a cookie..

```
setcookie('name', '0'); //start at 0
```

When the user selects an answer to the question; Compare that selection to what ever is in the database...
check answers:

```
public function checkAnswer() { 
      $questionid = $_POST['id'];//separate this question from the others
      $useranswer = $_POST['answer'];//get user's answer
      $dbanswer = getAnswer($questionid); //call a function that retrieves and returns the answer from the database, based on the given id (as an argument).

  if ($useranswer == $dbanswer)://compare answers
     andvanceQuestion();//advance to the next question
  else:
     incorrectAnswer();//tell user their answer was incorrect.
  endif;
}//end checkAnswer
```

advanceQuestion function:

```
public function advanceQuestion() {
   $currQuestion = $_COOKIE['name'];//get cookie value
   $nextQuestion = $currQuestion + 1;//increment cookie value
   $setcookie('name', $nextQuestion);//update cookie value
   header("location: /mysite/question.php?id=$currQuestion");//go to next question
}
```

getAnswer function:

```
public function getAnswer($id) {
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$id'");//simple mysql syntax
   $question = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);//create array of all the entries given by $query
   $answer = $question['answer'];//select the 'answer' field from the array

   return $answer;//return the value
}
```

getQuestion function:

```
public function getQuestion($id) {
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$id'");
   $question = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);//create array of all the entries given by $query
   $question = $question['question'];//select the 'question' field from the array

   return $question;//return the value
}
```

on question.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['answer']))://check if form was submitted
   $class->checkAnswer();//check
endif;

if (isset($_COOKIE['name']) && isset($_GET['id']))://check for url param and cookie
   if (!$_COOKIE['name'] == $_GET['id'])://compare the two
      header("location: mysite.com/CHEATER.php");//if they DONT match, CHEATER!
   else:
      ?>
      <p>Who is the world's best Programmer?</p><!--Get question from db-->
      <form method="post">
          <!--For each option found with question, echo them.-->
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>"/>
          Steve Jobs <input type="radio" name="answer" value="jobs"><br/>
          Steve Wozniak <input type="radio" name="answer" value="woz"><br/>
          Me? <input type="radio" name="answer" value="me"><br/>
          <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
      <?php
   endif;
endif;
```

Kinda wrote this quick so please excuse any small syntax errors.

That's pretty much it. But the BEST thing you can do for yourself, is study the language you will be using before you write large applications. Try to refrain from copying & pasting code. Always write it yourself. And stick with it. If you can write Javascript, you will feel right at home with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are beginner, start with something simple. When you start building up the application, think what you need first (**plan**). Sometimes the order of the functionalities matter, sometimes they don't matter that much.

In this case you could first do the quiz, without remembering user, but preventing proceed. At first stage you dont need DB, just a simple (maybe even one page) application. You application should:

```
1. show question to user
2. show answer possibilities to user
3. ask user response
4. intepret that response
5. if wrong, ask same question again, if right proceed to next, either way goto step 1
```

Whenever you have done that, you can proceed to phase 2, "remebering user". I think, the **simpliest way is to store user question number to the cookie**. I know it's not the best solution, having "holes" where user can proceed questions anyway he likes, but it's a start for beginner programmer. In PHP something like:

```
setcookie("question", $value);       <-- to set
$question = $_COOKIE["question"];    <-- to get value of cookie
```

Take a look of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

There are other ways to proceed, with user registration/login and all, but I think that is defenitely NOT "a first real program" to create.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with being a beginner. we all start somewhere :) 
one thing you will want to use is a database
depending on your server type and what configurations you have with your server you have many options but the common ones involve structured query language: the more commonly used ones are sqlite, mysql, and sqlserver. this will store the data for the users if you plan on having them come back (you may have to create a login at this point) 
another option (as opposed to a login) is to have cookies with the php (since session data is only stored temporarily) 
your question is quite broad so forgive me for only writing ways you can do it. 
in the database you can have it set for the users you can create a table like "is complete" and set it as true while querying the database to see if the question was correctly answered. 
if not answered have the questions ordered in a certain way so it would print out them by the chosen order etc.

Comment: You could also use some capital letters and divide your text into paragraphs, every once in a while :)

Comment: difficult to read u should highlight some main points